# How to use shopify Oauth token for later use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify

After a shop installs my app for their shop, it redirects to my website endpoint.

This is where I make a post request to get the permanent access token.

I will also check if the shop owner already has an account with us by seeing if their logged in or they can go and sign up or log in.

This is where I'm confused what to do.

How should I go about saving the token in reference to them if a) their not logged in and then log in, b) their not a user and need to sign up.

logically im thinking i should hold on to the Access Token some how but not sure how exactly.

Thanks

Comment: You can keep it in a database with the store name.

Comment: @drip but i don't have a user created at that point, nothing to save to.

Comment: Why do you need an user? You create an Access Token and that store will use that token as long as it doesn't uninstall the APP. You should check if the store name ( not the user ) is already in the database ( which it SHOULDN"T be, you must remove the access token once he deletes the APP, there is a webhook for the uninstall App ). After that you must use the hmac or some other way to validate the shop when he makes request. You should request the access token once, not multiply times.

Comment: @drip I would like to create my own user bc I have my own dashboard that I would like to have the user access and in that case I would need them to create an account with my backend. I am already doing the hmac to validate etc.

Comment: I think that you need to provide more information hete. The main idea of an APP is to get the access token with which you have the permission to communicate with the store. From there you can create users or what ever you like as long as you have the correct scopes. Now if you have a separate dashboard that has nothing to do with Shopify, then you are asking a totally different question that has nothing to do with the current topic. So I'm totally confused what is your question at the moment.

Comment: @drip What i am trying to achieve, is exactly how Shippo has it set up. Once you install your redirected to either login/register and then you go to the shippo dashboard.